# Scrapy spider scrape the last URL from the list of URLs in a text file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was iterating over a list of URLs in a text file but scrapy spider starts from the very last URL and exists after scraping it. It does not iterate over other URLs. What could be the reason for this?

You can find the code and the text file here:

https://github.com/CodeWithAwais/yell_spider.git

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text in question, not image, not link to external page.

Comment: BTW: shorter `links_list = open(..).read().split("\n")` and `start_urls = links_list`.

Comment: when you read lines from file you have to remove `\n` from the end of line. If you don't do this then you have string `"url\n"` and it is not correct URL. And if last line in file doesn't have `\n` then it gives you the only correct URL.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me without problem . You have to add more details in question. You have to add full error message in question (not in comment)

Comment: @furas yes it does work but unfortunately, it only scrapes one link from the text file and then spider is closed.

Comment: I run code and later check urls in browser and it shows me captcha. SO server blocks  script when it tries to get too much data. And this can be real problem. You may need to change in setting how long it sleeps between requests or you may need to use proxy servers for this.

Comment: see `scrapy` doc: [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) and [RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#randomize-download-delay)

Comment: Yes, there is a captcha so that's why I was using proxycrawl. I am now using crawlers with your method and it seems to be working fine. Proxycrawl has different methods with starturl so I think that's why it didn't work. Anyway thanks a lot for your help... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @furas, the follwoing code works fine:

```
links_list = open(..).read().split("\n") and start_urls = links_list
```